# cypress/included + "npm run xyz"

Tags: angular, cypress, e2e

While using cypress/included, is it possible to run a specific "npm run" command?

reason is i want to start an angular-app and THEN run the tests, but with that docker image.

(i tried to use my own image but it is missing a dep. "system is missing the dependency: Xvfb"